# About the Linkedin Oauth2,Which data should I used as a unique ID in my site

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I want Linkedin`member use their account login my web site,So I use Linkedin Oauth2, when user login by Linkedin Oauth2 , and I get the feedback data from Linkedin
some json like: {"firstName": "One`s name","id": "AString"}.

And I made a big mistake:
I used that "Id" as a user`s unique ID in my web site.

> **But I find the "id" will changing for a time.**

My question is : which data that from linkedin, should I use as a unique ID in my site?

Thank you in advance！

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry， I find the reason: I find some of my Linkedin test accounts with same name, So I mess up the id....